# Identifying the Web element which have same property (same class,same type,same name).Differance is only in value in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

After entering value”86100000” and clicking the “Search” button ,
Page will be reloaded and will get list of “Add to List” button under Commodity Section.

As “Search” and “Add to List” button have same property ,Not able to click “Add to List” button![Picture showing Search and Add to List Button]

**HTML tag for "Search" Button :**

**HTML tag for "Add to List" Button :**

Pls suggest way to identify "Add to List" button..I tried by xpath and CSS Selector.IDE is identifying that button.But in eclipse using selenium code is giving error and not able to locate element..

I need code to wait till the page gets loaded after clicking "Search" button and need to click ""Add to list" button..

Pls help me with ur ans..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

search xpath = //input[@value='Search'

add to list xpath = //input[@value='Add to list']

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to help you, can you paste the HTML of the page before and after the search. Then I will be able to give you some sample code.

Comment: **HTML tag for "Search" Button :**  (ie) Before search

<input class="vmBtnAddInline" type="button" onclick="quickSearch('registrationCommodity.do?quickEntries=','VM_inl_commodity_all'); return true;" value="Search" name="Button">

**HTML tag for "Add to List" Button :**    (ie) After search

<input class="vmBtnAddInline" type="button" onclick="parent.addCode(this,'86100000','Vocational training');" value="Add to list" name="Button" disabled="" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath locator to locate the first button:

```
//input[@value="Search" and @type="button"]
```

In WebDriver C#

```
var searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Search' and @type='button']"));
```

In order to locate the add to list button, use the following XPath:

```
//input[@value="Add to list" and @type="button"]
```

In WebDriver C#

```
var addToListButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Add to list' and @type='button']"));
```

Comment: thankx for ur reply..I ran the code.but showing error as "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value=\"Add to list\" and @type=\"button\"]"} Command duration or timeout: 50.11 seconds  " I think need to wait till page loads after clicking"search" button .I used " driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS); " code.still face the prob..How to wait till page loads and "Add to list" button is visible..

Comment: You can use the following extension method or write something similar to explicit wait the element:                                                                         public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
}

Comment: Also, you can search for an element availability with the following technique: new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(login))));

Comment: search button is identified by input[@value="Search" and @type="button"]. Once that search button is clicked page is refreshed and still "Add to List" button is not identified by //input[@value="Add to list" and @type="button"] even though it is identified by selenium IDE by "Find" button.. I am unable to fix the issue still now..Once "Add to List" is clicked  "86100000','Vocational training'" will be displayed in an frame .I will send the recorded video soon so that some body can help me..

Comment: If the result is displayed in frame, you need to switch to it before searching  for elements in it.                                                                                      var iFrameElement = Driver.FindElementByTagName("iFrame");
    var driver = Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(this.iFrameElement);    
    var element = driver.FindElement(selector);

Comment: Thanks.The element was loctaed in iFrame and now I am able to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

:nth-child(css selector) should be able to help you here.

Comment: search button is identified by input[@value="Search" and @type="button"]. Once that search button is clicked page is refreshed and still "Add to List" button is not identified by //input[@value="Add to list" and @type="button"] even though it is identified by selenium IDE by "Find" button.. I am unable to fix the issue still now..Once "Add to List" is clicked "86100000','Vocational training'" will be displayed in an frame .I will send the recorded video soon so that some body can help me..

Comment: try this.
your class name is "vmBtnAddInline" as per your comment search comes first and add to list comes next.
.vmBtnAddInline:nth-child(2) <and the rest of your selector >

Comment: Sandy, Thanks. Can u pls give the full code so that I can try that

Comment: .vmBtnAddInline:nth-child(2) input[type=button]                                       This should work. If it doesn't, check if the button displayed is disabled. if you are testing in any common website give me the url and I could offer more help.

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/BSGWwuGW  ..Pls have a look on this video and help me..